# Why every stochastic process is always written as a function of Brownian motion.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

For example,
$$
dS(t) = \alpha S(t) dt + \sigma S(t) dW(t)
$$
$$
dR(t) = (\alpha -\beta R(t))dt + \sigma dW(t)
$$
$$
dR(t) = (\alpha -\beta R(t))dt + \sigma \sqrt{R(t)} dW(t)
$$
There is always a Brownian motion / Wiener process ,"W(t)".

It looks like the standard Brownian motion "W(t)" is the atom of all kinds of stochastic process that Stochastic-Analysis studied. Why?

Are there any Theorems saying "All kinds of stochastic process could convert to a function of standard Brownian motion ,a.s.,  existing and unique."?

I know in the "Jump" circumstance, Poisson process is included. However, the kinds of "atom" process are still very rare.

Any hints or recommendation of papers or book chapters or web sites is of great grateful.Thanks.

Comment: The answer to your question is NO, still you could be interested in Ito representation Theorem.

Comment: @RScrlli Thank you. But i think Martingale representation theorem does not very suit this question. Martingale representation theorem is based on the probability filtration space by a  Brownian motion, while my question is about a possible different probability filtration space .

Comment: so you are thinking about possibly anticipating functionals of brownian motions? Still I believe the answer is NO. Notice that the examples you provided are SDEs driven by brownian motion, so the dependence of is trivial.